# Powershell .NET httpclient add header

Tags: powershell

I want to upload a file using powershell to a RestAPI. Sadly the invoke-restmethod does not support MultipartForm Uploads and even with building my own body it does not work. Therefore, I have to get this working using another way :)
Luckily I found this excellent blog post: http://blog.majcica.com/2016/01/13/powershell-tips-and-tricks-multipartform-data-requests/ and now I'm trying to build me a request using the .NET Client within Powershell. But I do hit my borders right now. I need to edit the standard header to add an authorization token. And I have no clue how! Would somebody please so kind and point me in the right direction how to do this? Thank you very much!

```
function Invoke-MultipartFormDataUpload
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM
    (
        [string][parameter(Mandatory = $true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$InFile,
        [string]$ContentType,
        [Uri][parameter(Mandatory = $true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Uri,
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
    )
    BEGIN
    {
        if (-not (Test-Path $InFile))
        {
            $errorMessage = ("File {0} missing or unable to read." -f $InFile)
            $exception =  New-Object System.Exception $errorMessage
            $errorRecord = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord $exception, 'MultipartFormDataUpload', ([System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidArgument), $InFile
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($errorRecord)
        }

        if (-not $ContentType)
        {
            Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

            $mimeType = [System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping($InFile)

            if ($mimeType)
            {
                $ContentType = $mimeType
            }
            else
            {
                $ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            }
        }
    }
    PROCESS
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http

        $httpClientHandler = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler

        if ($Credential)
        {
            $networkCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential @($Credential.UserName, $Credential.Password)
            $httpClientHandler.Credentials = $networkCredential
        }

        $httpClient = New-Object System.Net.Http.Httpclient $httpClientHandler

        $packageFileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream @($InFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)

        $contentDispositionHeaderValue = New-Object System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue "form-data"
        $contentDispositionHeaderValue.Name = "fileData"
        $contentDispositionHeaderValue.FileName = (Split-Path $InFile -leaf)

        $streamContent = New-Object System.Net.Http.StreamContent $packageFileStream
        $streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $contentDispositionHeaderValue
        $streamContent.Headers.ContentType = New-Object System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue $ContentType

        $content = New-Object System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent
        $content.Add($streamContent)

        try
        {
            $response = $httpClient.PostAsync($Uri, $content).Result

            if (!$response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                $responseBody = $response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                $errorMessage = "Status code {0}. Reason {1}. Server reported the following message: {2}." -f $response.StatusCode, $response.ReasonPhrase, $responseBody

                throw [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException] $errorMessage
            }

            return $response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
        }
        catch [Exception]
        {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
        finally
        {
            if($null -ne $httpClient)
            {
                $httpClient.Dispose()
            }

            if($null -ne $response)
            {
                $response.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    END { }
}
```

Comment: Hi @maigelnight I'm on the same track. Did you succeed with this? I need to add a header for basic authentication. I'm following the same blog post.

Comment: Hello,  $httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.add('Authorization', 'Basic <Token>')    #where <token> is a base64 basic auth token

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#Authorization
$httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New-Object System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", $accesstoken);
```